# Relaunch browser via Selenium remote webdriver after remote VM reboot

Tags: selenium, virtual-machine, ui-automation, remotewebdriver

I'm running selenium scripts on remote VM via selenium remote webdriver where for each test i will be rebooting the VM. Below is the sample program used where the browser launch fails for the second after VM reboot.

```
    WebDriver driver;
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities=new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "40.0.2");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "WINDOWS");
    capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "firefox");
    driver= new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://10.86.101.217:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    driver.quit();
// Rebooting the VM, Selenium server started after rebooting

    Thread.sleep(200000);
    System.out.println("end");

    driver= new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://10.86.101.217:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println("end 2");
```

Comment: After your VM gets Reboot..do you register that slave again? Thats important.

Comment: I'm running via remote webdriver. No Hub/node registration is done for all cases

Comment: sorry but you when you run on selenium grid you would need to register your nodes/slave to hub where you are sending all the tests to run

Comment: I'm using remote webdriver not grid. So i will be starting the selenium server in remote VM and run the scripts.

Comment: I think i found the issue. Can you try using driver.close() instead of driver.quit()